# Halo-created lens flares aren't rendering

Tags: materials, blender-internal-render-engine

I'm following the [Noob to Pro: Halo Materials tutorial](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Blender_3D:_Noob_to_Pro/Halo_Materials) and failing to get a lens flare effect that is displayed in the tutorial.

Compare the before image with the after image
[image: before image]

[image: after image]. There's no difference. The lens flare isn't being created and I've tried dozens of positions and fiddled pretty much every setting on the halo, removed the sun, added/removed lights, etc. I've gone to factory settings and re-done everything from scratch a couple of times now.

My computer is an Acer Aspire E1, I'm using Linux Mint 15, and have Intel's proprietary graphics installed. This is being attempted on blender version 2.75.

#### [Blend File](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37342)

Comment: Here is a link to the blend file - http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37342.

Comment: @MikePan I actually can't get it to work in 2.75, yet the same file works in 2.69.

Comment: I accidentally used 2.74 during the testing, now I can also confirm it does not work in 2.75. I think it's safe to say it's an unintended bug. Please report to https://developer.blender.org/

Comment: I confirm this issue. As far as I've noticed, since the release 2.75, this feature is no longer working. I've just tested in the most recent Release Candidate (2.76rc1), and it's still not fixed.